# UIScroll: enable touch event even when it is scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

How should I configurative my UIScrollView such that, a UIbutton's `forControlEvents:UIControlStateHighlighted`  can still be triggered when the scrollView is in the state of scrolling.

Now it simply stops the scrolling when touched, instead of highlighting the button even though the finger landed on it.

This is very expected, of course, but I would really appreaciate if someone can guide me to enabling button's touch event when scrolling.

Comment: post the code which u have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could try to subclass UIScrollView and override the hitTest method like this:

```
-(id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    id hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == yourButton) {
        return yourButton;
    } else { 
       return hitView;
    }
}
```

That way, when your button is being "hit", the button would receive the touch event instead of the UIScrollView.